# How to fix kubernetes nfs mount error no such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nfs

I am trying to use `NFS` volume in the same cluster I have deployed other k8s services. But one of the services using the `NFS` fails with 
`Output: mount.nfs: mounting nfs.default.svc.cluster.local:/opt/shared-shibboleth-idp failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory`

The `nfs PV`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: nfs.default.svc.cluster.local # nfs is from svc {{ include "nfs.name" .}}
    path: "/opt/shared-shibboleth-idp"
```

Description of `nfs service`

```
➜  helm git:(ft-helm) ✗ kubectl describe svc nfs
Name:              nfs
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=nfs
                   chart=nfs-1.0.0
                   heritage=Tiller
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          role=nfs
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.19.251.72
Port:              mountd  20048/TCP
TargetPort:        20048/TCP
Endpoints:         10.16.1.5:20048
Port:              nfs  2049/TCP
TargetPort:        2049/TCP
Endpoints:         10.16.1.5:2049
Port:              rpcbind  111/TCP
TargetPort:        111/TCP
Endpoints:         10.16.1.5:111
```

And the `nfs deployment`

```
➜  helm git:(ft-helm) ✗ kubectl describe replicationcontrollers telling-quoll-nfs
Name:         telling-quoll-nfs
Namespace:    default
Selector:     role=nfs
Labels:       app=nfs
              chart=nfs-1.0.0
              heritage=Tiller
Annotations:  <none>
Replicas:     1 current / 1 desired
Pods Status:  1 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  role=nfs
  Containers:
   nfs:
    Image:        k8s.gcr.io/volume-nfs:0.8
    Ports:        20048/TCP, 2049/TCP, 111/TCP
    Host Ports:   0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /exports from nfs (rw)
  Volumes:
   nfs:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  nfs-pv-provisioning-demo
    ReadOnly:   false
Events:         <none>
```

And where it is being used

```
volumeMounts:
   # names must match the volume names below
   - name: RELEASE-NAME-shared-shib
     mountPath: "/opt/shared-shibboleth-idp"
;
;
volumes:
  - name: RELEASE-NAME-shared-shib
    persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: nfs
;
;
```

k8s `version`

```
➜  helm git:(ft-helm) ✗ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-20T04:49:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.7-gke.8", GitCommit:"7d3d6f113e933ed1b44b78dff4baf649258415e5", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:37:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: sometimes you might have to create the folder or dir manually.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `/opt/shared-shibboleth-idp` directory exists on your nfs and that it is accessible

Comment: @PatrickW `/opt` is there but `shared-shibboleth-idp` is not. Which is exactly what I want to mount

Comment: So the mounting operation can only mount existing volumes and paths. The directory does not need to exist on the pod but it does have to exist on the nfs

Comment: I have to find a way to create it manually in Helm

Comment: you just need to have this directory in your nfs first. The directory in the pod will be created when the mount completes. But the source directory must exist on your NFS first

Comment: @Shammir did you solve it using damitj07 and Patrick W comments?

Comment: @KoopaKiller Yes, I used their suggestion and it fixed my issue

Comment: @Shammir please accept below answer. It will be more visible for community members with similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments made by `Patrick W` and `damitj07`:

You need have to create the folder or dir manually before try to mount, otherwise the Kubernetes will raise an error because the destination directory not exist.